# Is there an easy way (in PhpStorm) to wrap snippet of PHP code in PHPDoc?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Is there a way to copy some code and insert in into PHPDoc comment so that formatting remains the same?

I need to insert this snippet of code into phpcs for the function.

```
         [
            [
                '_is_forecast'  => true,
                '_is_fake_item'     => false,
                'humidity'          => 1.24,
                // ... other parameters
                'rain_intensity'    => 3,
                'timestamp'         => '2019-12-20 11:20 UTC',
            ],
            [
                '_is_forecast'  => true,
                '_is_fake_item'     => false,
                'humidity'          => 24.5,
                // ... other parameters
                'rain_intensity'    => 23,
                'timestamp'         => '2019-12-20 11:40 UTC',
            ],
        ];
```

so it then should look like this:

```
/**
 *
 *        [
 *            [
 *                '_is_forecast'  => true,
 *                '_is_fake_item'     => false,
 *                'humidity'          => 1.24,
 *                / ... other parameters
 *                'rain_intensity'    => 3,
 *                'timestamp'         => '2019-12-20 11:20 UTC',
 *            ],
 *            [
 *                '_is_forecast'  => true,
 *                '_is_fake_item'     => false,
 *                'humidity'          => 24.5,
 *                / ... other parameters
 *                'rain_intensity'    => 23,
 *                'timestamp'         => '2019-12-20 11:40 UTC',
 *            ],
 *        ];
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function groupByParams()
{
   return [];
}
```

Comment: You can use [Multiple Carets functionality](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/working-with-source-code.html#multiple_cursor) to bulk add `*` at those newly pasted lines. P.S. If formatting gets changed during paste -- try using "Edit | Paste without Formatting" instead of ordinary Paste (which may indent/reformat code based on your settings).

Answer (score 2):

Usually I select the block of the text I want to comment and press `CTRL + /` or `CTRL + SHIFT + /` depending upon the comment type I want to get.

PHPStorm will apply the comment based on the type of the file you are currently editing.

You un-comment the block using the same keystroke combination.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use live template of PHPStrom ctr+alt+s open setting. search live template. and create your template. and set small abbreviations for that then you can easily access anywhere that template. or in your case commented code. in file. by just using. ctr+j  select your abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Comment with Block Comment` from the `Code` menu, in the menu bar